# Trying to use UpdateCursor on Branch versioned layer - RuntimeError: cannot open workspace

Tags: arcpy, versioning, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I have a branch versioned service layer on ArcGIS Portal. I want editors to use ArcGIS Pro to open a map in a ArcGIS Pro project and use their respective versions of this layer to create new features based off of a reference table that has all of the attributes for the features after they've been drawn in.

I would like the editor to copy and paste the UID from the reference table to their version of feature layer and move onto drawing the next feature. A script will run during non-business hours to run a post from the editor version to the default version leaving the newly created features' attributes blank except for the UIDs.

I would then like the script to populate these attributes using an update cursor.

I have successfully signed into portal using arcgis.GIS and generated the necessary access token used in my url query, I have also done the following:

```
# list of UIDs with null attribute values in feature layer named "UIDS"
# make a dict named "updates" using each item in UIDS as a key and the pair being the attribute values to be carried over to the feature layer

# import modules
import arcpy
from arcgis.gis import GIS

# set up layer for editing
workspace = r"https://url.org/arcgis/rest/services/Map_Docs/FeatureServer?token=" + token
smd = r"https://url.org/arcgis/rest/services/Map_Docs/FeatureServer/0?token=" + token
lyr = "lyr"

# I have done all the necessary steps to connect to portal at this point

arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(smd,lyr)
arcpy.management.ChangeVersion(lyr, 'BRANCH', "sde.DEFAULT")
```

This is where things go sideways:

```
with arcpy.da.Editor(workspace) as edit:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyr, ["UID","Date", "Street"]) as rows:
        for row in rows:
            for k, v in updates.items(): # k =m UID, v = row[1:2]
                if k == row[0]:
                    row[1] = v[0]
                    row[2] = v[1]
                rows.updateRow(row)
```

This is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [25]:
Line 1:     with arcpy.da.Editor(workspace) as edit:

RuntimeError: cannot open workspace
```

What do I need to do to open the workspace? I've already generated a token and have successfully tested the query string by pasting it into a private browse for access to both the feature service (FeatureServer/0?token=" + token) and the feature server (FeatureServer?token=" + token)

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly confident that Branch Versioning doesn't support direct editing.  I think you are going to need to switch to Traditional versioning to use your update cursor.  Or look to the GIS module to run your edits through the REST service.